Why does the folder check in Terraform contradict my Python output?
I am a newbee when it comes to Terraform providers which may explain why I have the following problem on my Ubuntu 24.04 V. First, here is the main.tf file:
terraform {
  required_providers {
    flowtrends = {
      source  = "local/flowtrends"
      version = "1.0.0"
    }
  }
}
 
provider "flowtrends" {}

I executed this commandline statement:
python3 -c "import os; print('Folder exists' if os.path.isdir(os.path.expanduser('~/.terraform.d/plugins')) else 'Folder does not exist')"

Output: "Folder exists"
In addition, I also executed this:
python3 -c "import os; print('Folder exists' if os.path.isdir(os.path.expanduser('~/.terraform.d/plugins2')) else 'Folder does not exist')"

Output: "Folder does not exist"
Apparently, the python statement checks the path correctly. If a folder really does not exist, this is confirmed. If it exists, it is also confirmed.
However, when typing
terraform init

I got this output:
"... ~/.terraform.d/plugins: no such file or directory..."
So the output of terraform contradicts the python output. I have no idea why. I am sure the folder exists. I checked that manually and programmatically (python). I really do not understand why terraform denies this. It is blocking me from working with terraform. Because logically, when a folder exists, it exists. Terraform should use that folder when needed instead of denying the reality. I cannot create a folder that already exists so I cannot fix it.
Who can help me resolving this discrepancy so I can continue working with my terraform providers?
My work is also shown in the attached screenshot:


UPDATE
The .terraformrc file in ~:
provider_installation {
  filesystem_mirror {
    path = "~/.terraform.d/plugins"
  }
}

The version output of terraform:
Terraform v1.10.3
on linux_amd64

It would be logical to just use absolute path but unfortunately, terraform gets the idea then to search in the registry instead of locally. Maybe I should find a way to FORCE terraform to only search locally? How?


Your desktop environment appears to be Linux. Can you confirm these results in a normal shell environment outside of the VSCode environment?

Yes. I updated the question to demonstrate this.

are you using custom configuration in a terraform.rc file? If so can you share that. If you use the explicit path does it work? have you tried putting the plugin/provider in the default plugin paths described here https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/cli/config/config-file#implied-local-mirror-directories

Can you also show the full output of terraform --version

@ChrisDoyle comment probably answer since this is using non-default directory. It is also worth noting that if the end goal here is to acceptance test a custom plugin provider then using the terraform-plugin-testing module would probably be easier.

I hope I can get a solution now as I got more info added in the UPDATE section.

@MatthewSchuchard Thanks for your suggestion but I am not familiar with such testing yet. But I hope the update will help solving the issue.

Why on earth are you using python to test the existence of a directory?  Just use a plain ls command, for goodness sake!

@JohnGordon Good point but has to do such a check in python anyway (as it was part of a python script). But ls is more logical. Both approaches are valid.

What output do you get from this command ls -ld ~/.terraform.d/plugins

@JohnGordon The output is: drwxrwxrwx 3 daan-xxxx-daan-xxxx 4096 Dec 30 13:53 /home/daan-xxxx/.terraform.d/plugins  (xxxx is a replacement of my family name)

I'm going to guess that the .terraformrc file does not know about ~ path expansion, so it is treating path = "~/.terraform.d/plugins" as a literal pathname that includes an actual ~ character.  Try editing that file to replace ~ with the actual full path name.

In general, only shell commands are guaranteed to properly handle ~ path expansion.  In any other context, it may or may not work.
